# FPDF + FPDI together?

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

I am using FPDF to generate PDF contracts, however people in office often forgets to print ToS file with them and they want me to add ToS into every contract, but when I try to use both FPDF and FPDI it shows me err 500, I've never worked with those two so I am not sure if I can use it that way.
Thanks in advance, Lucas.

EDIT:

```
<?
require_once('_inc/fpdf.php');
require_once('_inc/fpdi/fpdi.php');

$doc = new FPDF();
$tos = new FPDI();

$doc->whtml("blahblah");
$tos->AddPage();
$tos->setSourceFile('ToS.pdf');
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
$tos->useTemplate($tplIdx);
$tos->Output();

$doc->Output();
```

Comment: Without code it would be difficult to help you...

Comment: you try, you show, you say where you stuck, you receive support. easy no?

Comment: 1) The error is on which line? 2) What error message is returned? 3) Which version of FPDI you use?